# Is it possible to add the condition attribute name through input parameter in fetch xml ssrs report?

Tags: reporting-services, report, dynamics-crm, ssrs-2012, fetchxml

I have a requirement where user can select either of two types of dates 
1. Accident Date
2. Created Date 
From Drop Down. On the Basis of that User will fill the Date Range.
My Problem is how I can achieve this I have two different fields in the entity for this.
I have tried this

```
 <filter type="and">
      <condition attribute="@DateType" operator="on-or-after" value="@FromDate" />
      <condition attribute="@DateType" operator="on-or-before" value="@ToDate"   />

    </filter>
```

But I don't think so it works. So is there any another way to achieve this.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an easy way to achieve it due to it being fetch xml and the language being quite limited. But there is a bit of a "hack" to achieve this.

Firstly, I am presuming that the value of value of "@DateType" is the name of the attribute you want to filter the date range on.

Now, to achieve what you want you basically need to hijack the prefiltering with a parameter of your own. Remove the filter from your main query and enable prefiltering. Something like the following (in my case I was testing it on lead):

```xml
<fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="false">
  <entity name="lead" enableprefiltering="true" prefilterparametername="FilterParam">
    <attribute name="fullname" />
    <attribute name="createdon" />
    <attribute name="modifiedon" />
    <attribute name="statuscode" />
    <attribute name="subject" />
    <attribute name="ownerid" />
    <attribute name="leadid" />
    <order attribute="createdon" descending="true" />
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

The important part being the **`enableprefiltering="true" prefilterparametername="FilterParam"`** and the referenced prefiltering parameter `FilterParam` (you can name this whatever you want).

Now, this should have automatically created a new parameter called `FilterParam` for you. Open the properties of that parameter and edit the Default Value to read this instead:

```vb
= "<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>" + 
"<entity name='lead'><all-attributes/>" + 
"<filter type='and'>" + 
"<condition attribute='" + Parameters!DateType.Value + "' operator='on-or-after' value='" + Format(Parameters!DateFrom.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") + "' />" +
"<condition attribute='" + Parameters!DateType.Value + "' operator='on-or-before' value='" + Format(Parameters!DateTo.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") + "' />" +
"</filter></entity></fetch>"
```

Basically you're using an expression in the parameter to build a FetchXML string to pass in as the prefilter. This uses the date parameters to create the correct filter.

Now run it and it should be filtering by 2 different dates.

Comment: Thanks! As per the answer you have given what I understood is we are pre filtering the record but that's not the case. User want to select either of the two dates either accident date or created date. But not the pre filtered record.

Comment: Not quite what I'm saying. What I'm saying is you can use the same prefiltering parameters to achieve what you asked. I have presumed by the nature of your query that you aren't currently prefiltering.