# SSRS - The report parameter has a defaultValue or a ValidValue that depends on the report parameter

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, dynamics-crm, report, fetchxml

In an SSRS report, I have a fetchXML query that is dependent on the parameters that the users will choose from the UI that are defined in the report:

```
    <fetch xmlns:generator="MarkMpn.SQL4CDS">
  <entity name="new_r10logentries">
    <attribute name="new_quarter" />
    <attribute name="new_cr884_company" />
    <link-entity name="cr884_company" to="new_cr884_company" from="cr884_companyid" alias="cr884_company" link-type="inner">
      <attribute name="cr884_company" />
      <attribute name="cr884_companyid" />
      <filter>
        <condition attribute="cr884_company" operator="eq" value="@CompanyParam">
          <value />
        </condition>
      </filter>
    </link-entity>
    <filter>
      <condition attribute="new_quarter" operator="eq" value="@QuarterParam" />
    </filter>
  </entity>
</fetch>
```

The parameters settings that I have are the below:
[image]

The companyParam is based on the dataset of the fetchXML and will populate the list of the companies' names.
The quarterParam is a list of options that are not based on the dataset.

When trying to publish/preview the report I got the below error:
[image]

Knowing I am passing the param as per the above query and the company column name that I am querying against is of type text and not GUID:

[image]

I hardcoded the company name in the query it works perfectly and in the parameters, it populates the list of the companies in the UI. However, when I pass the param in the fetchXML nothing happens as the CompanyName in the UI display null values.

Could you please support solving this issue? I have spent 3 hours changing in query with no result.

Resources that I look for support:

[Input parameter SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42779605/is-it-possible-to-add-the-condition-attribute-name-through-input-parameter-in-fe)

[Community Dynamics](https://community.dynamics.com/365/b/ajitpatra365crm/posts/ssrs-the-report-parameter-p1-has-a-defaultvalue-or-a-validvalue-that-depends-on-the-report-parameter-p2-forward-dependencies-are-not-valid)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `CompanyParam` is list of companies which you retrieve from `Dataset1` (from screenshot--> get values from query).

You pass this list(companies) selected one comapny by user to same `dataset1` to retrieve your result and this is your circular reference.

Create a new Dataset "DatasetRetrieveCompanies" This dataset will give you all companies based on your fetchxml. Then add this dataset to your CompanyParam (get values from query). This should most probably solve your issue

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I got it working now based on your suggestion, the trick was to create a different dataset to get the list of companies and map it to the CompanyParam to get the values.

Answer (score 1):

I have almost zero experience with FetchXML so this is just an educated guess...

I would have expected you to have 2 datasets defined in your report.

1. Gets a list of companies based on `QuarterParam`
2. Gets the data for the report output based on `CompanyParam`

But it appears that you only have 1.

If I understand the XML you posted correctly, it looks like you have a parameter called 'CompanyParam' that uses a dataset that has a filter, the filter uses 'CompanyParam' - which is not possible, its a circular reference.

Comment: Hello Alan, the list of companies will be only populated by the CompanyParam and as for the quarterParam it is simply a dropdown (Q1,Q2..) and not dependent on a dataset. The main goal to achieve is when the user selects the company it should be passed to the query and populate the data. What will be the workaround the solve this issue since it's a circular reference?

Comment: Thats the bit I don't understand. How can you have a list of companies that depends on a company parameter? Typically you would have a list of companies that populates parameter options, the users chooses one of more of those companies and those chosen values are passed to another dataset which retrieves the main data for the report.